# Reading CSV file Into a Dictionary (KeyError: '","')

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to read a CSV file into a Dictionary, here is my code:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('/Users/m/based_final.csv',mode='r') as my_input_file:
    csv_reader=csv.DictReader(my_input_file)
    line_count=0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(str.format('Column names are {",".join(row)}'))
            line_count += 1

        print(str.format('\t{row["Indication"]} {row["Name"]} {row["Drug id"]} {row["Synonyms"]} '))
        line_count += 1
    print('Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

But I get this error:
KeyError: '","'.

Here is how data looks like:

```
Indication      Name            Drug id                                Synonyms 
for_treatment   bivalirudin     ['db00006', 'btd00076']                ['bivalirudina', 'bivalirudinum', 'hirulog'] 
for_alteplase   a name          ['db00009', 'btd00050', 'biod00050']   ['alteplase (genetical recombination)', 'alteplase, recombinant']
```

Any idea how this can be fixed?
Thx

Comment: Please do _not_ include data screenshots. In this particular case, we have no idea how the actual data looks like, and that's exactly what the parser complains about. Please include the text data. Please also include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: Corrected! @DYZ thanks!

Comment: So, are your columns actually tab-separated, not comma-separated? Also, please include the full error message.

Comment: @DYZ yes. It is tab separated but still with using "\t", I get this error "KeyError: '"\t"'.

Comment: `print('Processed {line_count} lines.')` will print "Processed {line_count} lines.". You probably want `print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')`. (Mind the `f` in front of the string.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code fixed with comments telling what I changed, however, you need to change the first line in the file to work with this code. The CVS file's first line needs to be formatted. each key that you want in your dictionary needs to have a coma after it. There can not be any space surrounding the coma either.

```
import csv
import sys

with open('/Users/m/based_final.csv',mode='r') as my_input_file:
    csv_reader=csv.DictReader(my_input_file)
    line_count=0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(str.format(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')) # an f added before the single quotes and a space after the coma for readibility
            line_count += 1

        print(str.format(f'\t{row["Indication"]} {row["Name"]} {row["Drug id"]} {row["Synonyms"]} ')) # same thing with the f
        line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.') # ditto
```

Comment: thx. But now I  get this error: TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, NoneType found. The error is on this line:   print(str.format(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')).  @Gabriel Tucker

Comment: No problem @nina_dev